# Editor-only MonoBehaviour (not GameObject)

Tags: unity, c#, editors

I'm well aware of the `EditorOnly` tag on game objects. However, my question is slightly different:

I have a large number of game objects in my scene that only mark a spot; i.e. I only care about their transform (position). I use a simple `OnDrawGizmos` script on them simply to have them visible in the editor.

I would like that script to not be exported into the build. It does nothing I need in the build, it is only useful for the editor.

My current workaround is to have it on a child game object that is set to `EditorOnly`, but that's kind of a hack and forces more workarounds in other parts of the code (that assign children to those marker points in-game, etc.)

Is there a way to mark a **script** as "editor-only" in Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your whole class in an `#if UNITY_EDITOR` preprocessor directive so that in a build it compiles to an empty file, like this:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;

public class EditorMarker : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnDrawGizmos() {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, 1);
    }
}
#endif
```

This will still attach a component to the object at runtime, but it will be a `null` component with no stored data, no behaviours, no message hooks.

---

Though for the specific use case of making invisible objects visible in-editor, another alternative you may want to consider is doing away with your `OnDrawGizmos` script entirely, and using [Unity's built-in icon system](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/AssigningIcons.html):

[image: Selecting icon in inspector]

By clicking on the icon to the left of a game object's name, you can select a label or icon style to use for that object, including a selection of built-in options, or you can assign a custom sprite of your own creation.

[image: Selection of icons/labels on empty game objects, as seen in the Inspector]

These icons are visible in the Scene view, but are not shown in the built executable, so you don't need to make a custom script that excludes itself from builds.

[You can also assign these icons through script](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility.SetIconForObject.html), if you want to avoid manual setup steps or creating prefabs for each kind of marker object.

Comment: Accepting this answer. It's not the solution I was looking for, but is apparently the closest that you can get in Unity.